# Where are my targets in Xcode 4?

Tags: xcode, xcode4, target

In Xcode 3, I had a list of targets in the left column. They're not there anymore. There's a list in the Scheme pull-down, but I can't find them anywhere else. Have they changed name to "Schemes"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Targets are still there. Click on the project (the very first object in the tree) in the project navigator and you'll get a view with project settings on the right and targets on the left.

Comment: I still get the same Error.

Answer (score 6):

Click the button as below images

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Click on the top level item in the left hand project view - it will show you the project and the targets in the main pane - along with their configurations

Answer (score 0):

No, targets and schemes are not the same thing. Your targets are still there: in the navigator in the left, click on the Project icon (it says "1 target, iOS SDK 4.3" or something similar underneath the usual .xcodeproject icon). THe main view now shows the project editor, where you can see and edit all your targets.

Schemes are basically ways to aggregate targets in useful ways when performing common actions like building and testing.

Answer (score -1):

Yep, they are inside "Schemes" now. Each scheme can contain differing targets/build configurations.

If you click the dropdown and choose "Edit Scheme..." where your targets used to be in Xcode 3, then click "Run AppName..." or "Test" in the left side tree, under the "Info" tab you'll find the Build Configuration dropdown that contains Debug, Release, etc. in addition to the target Executable.